# Woocomerce tax by user role and tag on variable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

In woocomerce, I need to exclude some products from lower tax calculation to a tag and a user role.
The code I developed works only for simple products, if I have products with variable how can I proceed?

Not only must they calculate but also see them without taxes

```
    function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {

// ottengo il tag prodotto
if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'tax_free' ) &&  in_array('13783', $product->tag_ids) ) {

        /* verificio se un prodotto ha figli */
        if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

            add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );


        } else {

            $tax_class = 'No tax aliquote';
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );

        }

}
return $tax_class;
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
```

For example, a user with "No-Tax" role must be able to see and purchase only products that have a tax-free tag without taxes.
The code I did is the one above, but only works with simple products those with the variables adds the label but does not eliminate the fees.

Comment: If elaborated with example, would have been better.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the request I hope it is clearer now